# WCF Username and Password in SOAP Header

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, soap

I'm trying to get a WCF client to call a web service with security information provided in the SOAP Header of the request, as follows.

```xml
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
                    xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" 
                    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
                    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
                    xmlns:ah_etas_order="http://types.defra.gov.uk/ahw/eartagging/order"
                    xmlns:ah_common="http://types.defra.gov.uk/ahw/common/complextypes" 
                    xmlns:ah_assettype="http://types.defra.gov.uk/ahw/asset"
                    xmlns:ah_ref_data_sets="http://types.defra.gov.uk/ahw/common/referencedatasets"
                    xmlns:ah_custtype="http://types.defra.gov.uk/ahw/customer" 
                    xmlns:m5="http://types.defra.gov.uk/bs7666" 
                    xmlns:m6="http://www.govtalk.gov.uk/people/bs7666" 
                    xmlns:m7="http://types.defra.gov.uk/ahw/common/derivedtypes" 
                    xmlns:ah_etas_type="http://types.defra.gov.uk/ahw/eartagging">
    <SOAP-ENV:Header xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
        <wsse:Security soap:role="system" soap:mustUnderstand="true">
            <wsse:UsernameToken>
                <wsse:Username>username here</wsse:Username>
                <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">password here</wsse:Password>
            </wsse:UsernameToken>
        </wsse:Security>
    </SOAP-ENV:Header>
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>...</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

I'm using Visual Studio 2012 and .NET 4. The docs say the version of SOAP messaging used for CARA Services is SOAP 1.2.

I've added a service reference with has added a web.config file with an endpoint and the following custom binding.

```xml
<customBinding>
    <binding name="ProcessOrderBinding">
        <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap12" />
        <httpTransport />
    </binding>
</customBinding>
```

I've tried lots of different web.config options but can't seem to get the correct soap header. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

#### Update:

@Yaron, Here is the soap header using your binding. I've added a includeTimestamp=false to remove the timestamp.

```xml
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" 
            xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
    <s:Header>
        <h:Security xmlns:h="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd"
                    xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd"
                    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
                    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" />
        <VsDebuggerCausalityData xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/vstudio/diagnostics/servicemodelsink">
            uIDPoxqYDT0sMwVImscgqVaf7GYAAAAAjin6KftLjkaS2CW99IXxrnWGCjfQnzFFuf4zGaQpeqIACQAA
        </VsDebuggerCausalityData>
        <o:Security s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:o="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
            <o:UsernameToken u:Id="uuid-79885712-d6eb-451c-9483-4df2b68722bd-1">
                <o:Username>username here</o:Username>
                <o:Password>password here</o:Password>
            </o:UsernameToken>
        </o:Security>
    </s:Header>
    <s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">...</s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

As you can see it's missing the following before the password.

```xml
<wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this binding:

```xml
<customBinding>
    <binding name="NewBinding0">
        <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap12" />
        <security authenticationMode="UserNameOverTransport">
            <secureConversationBootstrap />
        </security>
        <httpsTransport />
    </binding>
</customBinding>
```

Of course you also need to supply user/pass on the proxy:

```
proxy.ClientCredentials.Username.Username = "user"
proxy.ClientCredentials.Username.Password = "pass"
```

All this assumes you also use SSL. If you don't then check out [CUB](http://webservices20.blogspot.co.il/2008/11/introducing-wcf-clearusernamebinding.html).

Comment: Thanks Yaron but it's not putting in the following before the password. <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">

Comment: please publish the full message it generates now

Comment: Hi Yaron. I've added the full message to the original question.

Comment: how did you get this message? Fiddler is the only reliable way since the WCF log may not show exaclty the message. If indeed this attribute is not added I suggest you do not configure WCF to any security and manually push the username header to the message via a message inspector or a custom header

Comment: I used fiddler2 to get the xml sent.

Comment: in this case the easiest will be to use a message inspector or custom header as I mentioned above. although when the Type attribute is absent the default is Text so this should not matter. You could try send this message with soapUI (and add the Type attribute) to see if this is really the problem before you write the inspector.